# setTimeout not working properly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a script where I disable a button after it was clicked, for like 5 seconds, and then enable it again.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    var htmls = $(this).html();
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        $(this).html(htmls);
    }, 5000);
    $(this).html('<img src="<?=CDN(' / icons / loading / loading5.gif ')?>" />');
});
```

Somehow the `setTimeout` won't end, so the button won't be enabled again. I don't get any error messages.

Comment: The timeout ends, but `this` does not refer to the DOM element. Learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save `$(this)` into variable before `setTimeout` call, since `this` keyword inside `setTimeout` handler refers to `window` object:

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        htmls = $this.html();

    $this.prop("disabled", true)
         .html('<img src="..." />');

    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.prop("disabled", false)
            .html(htmls);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here  does not refer to the DOM element.Try to put into another temarory variable.Because it is outside to `setTimeOut`

```
 var $this = $(this),
        htmls = $this.html();

    $this.prop("disabled", true);
    setTimeout(function() {
       $this.prop("disabled", false).html(htmls);
    }, 5000);
```